# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.webkit.WebView.evaluateJavascript Android 6

Tags: android

Looks like this is a repeat question but its not indeed.  This happens in Android 6.

I am just using the following code to button onclick in MainActivity.

```
    alert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {    
            webView.evaluateJavascript("console.log(window.getSelection().baseNode.nodeValue);", null);             
        }
    });
```

Here I am getting the following error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(601): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.webkit.WebView.evaluateJavascript
```

I seen articles and forums says this has been rectified from verion 4.2.

How this occurred in Android  6.0

Comment: which one did you import?

Comment: I cant understand your question... I am new to Android..can you pls little elaborate?

Comment: webView - you imported it, show me its path, is it like import android.webkit.WebView or?

Comment: import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;